# Render async component in React Router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-router, react-router-v4

I want to render a component based on the payload it receives from an api like below

```
<Route path="/foo/bar" render={() => {
  return (get('/some/api').then((res) => {
    return <Baz data={res.data} />
          }).catch((err) => console.log))
        }} />
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you 
meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

even when I do wrap `Baz` in `[]`

Comment: `render` is synchronous. you need to have some state that you set from the response of your api call. there are many ways to do this, many of them very simple, but at a minimum you need to use state somewhere to handle the api response

Answer (score 16, accepted):

unfortunately with the latest version of React - 16. Async rendering is not an option yet.

With React Router v4, the `render` props of `Route` component expects a valid React Element or array of React Elements to be returned, therefore, it doesn't accept the Promise object return from your function.

However, it's not impossible to achieve what you want with the current version of React and React Router. You just need to tweak your code a little bit. Instead of returning a Promise, your `render` should return a React Component, then you can do conditional rendering based on async value inside that component.

It should look like:

```
<Route path="/foo/bar" render={BazWrapper} />


class BazWrapper extends React.Component {

    // Do asynchronous action here
    async componentDidMount() {
       try {
          const apiValue = await get('/some/api');
          this.setState({ apiValue })
       } catch(err) {
          // error handling
       }
    }

    render() {
        const { apiValue } = this.state; 
        return <Baz data={apiValue} />;
    }

}
```

By calling `setState` after the asynchronous call finish, you let React Component know that the data is ready and it's should re-render the component.

Comment: small correction, should be `render={BazWrapper}`. or `render={props =>
 <BazWrapper {...props} />}`

Comment: also, just a suggestion, but that wrapper class could be made more reusable by passing `apiValue` to `children` instead of hardcoding `<Baz />` into it

Comment: hi @azium, thanks for your comment, I made the correction. The render function return <Baz> is definitely just an example based the one provided on the question.

Comment: Your workaround make Baz component render twice, the first with no data.

Comment: It's not a workaround, it just how React and React Router works. Also, it's also recommended by `React` dev team themselves to use `componentDidMount` to get  data from external source, if you don't want `Baz` component to render without data, simply make it a conditional render.

Comment: If I understand the question is want to resolve data from api before navigate to target page. So your solution doesn't match. Because it navigate immediate without waiting for data.

I'm spending many days to find the way React-Router resolve data like browsers do, but no hope.

Comment: The question is very clear: `I want to render a component based on the payload it receives from an api`, it has nothing to do which when the data api is loaded. Can you please point out which part of the question stated that the data must be resolved before the target page is loaded ? Also, holding up navigating the page is a bad practice as it is not a standard behaviour that users expect from the browser. Next time, before saying an answer is invalid, get your fact right.